# Python, combine list and array into paired list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list and an array. How would I combine each first row together? (Python)

eg.

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

and

```
[a,b]
[c,d]
[e,g]
```

and would like them in one list to look like:

```
[1, a,b]
[2, c,d]
[3, e,g]
```

Thanks all!

Comment: This is covered in numerous other questions but is also related to basic python functionality that is covered in essentially any guide online on how to learn Python. There for I'm voting to close this.

Comment: What is the second item? Is it a list within list?

Answer (score 3):

```
[row1 + row2 for row1, row2 in zip(list, array)]
```

Comment: This will only work if the elements of `list` and `array` are also list.